# Javascript single use variable declaration

Tags: javascript, performance

This may be a obvious question, but I was wondering if there was an efficiency difference between declaring something in a one time use variable or simply executing the code once (rather then storing it then using it). For example

```
var rowId = 3,
updateStuff(rowId);
```

VS

```
updateStuff(3);
```

Comment: If you're not going to use that value after passing it to `updateStuff`, don't put it in a variable first. The advantage I see is that it is more readable by using a variable. It has the capability of being captured by a closure and possibly never being released/GC'ed. But that, and efficiency of **this**, shouldn't be a concern

Comment: if there is a difference it is miniscule. you should be more worried about code reuse and readability depending on what you are doing. if rowID is always set to 3 and is never used anywhere else then there is no point in using a variable for it. however if you plan on expanding your code in the future and may want to change/reuse the rowID then I would use a variable.

Comment: I am sifting through a large code base that does this all over the place (with no intent to expand those sections) so I was just curious if it would be worth cleaning up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that worrying about performance in this instance is largely irrelevant. These sorts of micro-optimizations don't really buy you all that much. In my opinion, the readability of the code here is more important, since it's better to identify the `3` as `rowId` than leaving it as a magic number.

If you are really concerned about optimization, minimizing your code with something like [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/) would help; it has many tools that will help you make your code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using google closure to compile and if you annotated the var as a constant (as it appears in your example), I suspect the compiler would remove the constant and replace it with the literal.

My advice is to pick the readable option and if you really need the micro-optimizations and reduction in source size, use the google closure compiler or a minifier-- a tool is more likeley to accumulate enough micro-optimizations to make something noticeably faster, although I'd guess most of the saved milliseconds would come from reduced network time from minification.

And var declarations do take time and if you added that var to the global namespace, then there is one more thing that will be searched during resolving names.

Answer (score 0):

With a modern browser that compiles your code, the generated code will be exactly the same unless the variable is referenced somewhere else also.

Even with an old browser if there is a difference it won't be something to worry about.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:**

`delete` does not apply to non-objects, therefore my initial response was wrong. Furtermore  since the variable rowId is declared with the flag `var` it will be cleaned up by the garbage collection. Was it on the other hand defined without, it would live for the duration of the page / application.

source: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/

---

The variable rowId will be kept in memory and will not be released by the garbage collector since it's referenced to. Unless you release it afterwards like below it will be there till the end of the programs life. Also remember it take time to create the variable (minimal, but you asked)

```
   var rowId = 3
   updateStuff(rowId); 
   delete rowId
```

With efficiency in mind, then yes there is a difference. Your second example is the quickest and doesn't spend any extra resources.

OBS. Some languages do optimize code as such and simply remove the sequence, but I strongly doubt that JavaScript does so.

Comment: You can't delete vars only object properties.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: It will be released as long as nothing in `updateStuff` keeps a reference to it (or after those references are released)

Comment: Thanks for you response guys! I've overlooked the property of the `var` flag. 
ref: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/ (edit inc)